# Does specifying a constructor as noexcept implicitly result in the nothrow version of the new operator being used in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, noexcept, nothrow

If I specify a constructor as `noexcept`, does the `nothrow` version of the `new` operator implicitly get used when the object is dynamically instantiated?

For example:

```
class Something {
public:
  Something() noexcept;
};

...

Something *s = new Something;  // <- compiler interprets as "std::nothrow"
```

I understand that the practical result of using `noexcept` is that any exception thrown during execution of the function results in `std::terminate`, I just didn't know if the compiler makes the inference to use `nothrow` for the construction. My intuition says "no,"  and that a problem during allocation will result in `std::bad_alloc` being thrown, and thus result in `std::terminate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception is for *memory allocation*, not for the initialization or construction of the object.

So to answer your question: No, the compiler won't treat that as a no-throw `new`.